# How to get XPath values using Javascript on Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I'm facing some issues.
I would like to grab some currency values from a web page and show the sum of those currency values in euros (€) on Google chrome's extension in text format.

Let me show you what I have done so far.

The web page contains 3 currency amounts:

- **Dollar**
- **Pound**
- **Euro**

I have located the **XPath** of those variables:

- **Dollar:**`//*[@id=\"TotalSection\"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]`
- **Pound:**`//*[@id=\"TotalSection\"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]`
- **Euro:**`//*[@id=\"TotalSection\"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]`

I have created 3 files for Google Chrome Extension:

- **manifest.json** - Google Chrome Extension
- **getValues.js**  - Javascript File to get currency values and make the sum
- **showroom.html** - HTML file where the sum result will be printed.

Now let's have a look to the code:

**manifest.json**

```
    {
    "name": "Get Currency",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Get Currency € Calculator ",
    "browser_action": 
    {
        "default_icon": "boxicon.png",
        "default_title": "Get Currency € Calculator",
        "default_popup": "showroom.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
                            "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
                            "js": ["jquery-3.2.0.js","getValues.js"]
                        }],

    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
    "icons": 
    {
        "128": "boxicon.png"
    }
}
```

**getValues.js**

```
  function initialize() 
    {
      var element = document.evaluate('/html/body/div[2]/div[12]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = element;
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

**showroom.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
    <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 

    <title>Currency € Calculator </title> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="getValues.js"></script>

    <base target="_blank">

</head>


<body bgcolor="#FFF"> 
        <div id="total"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to write text in the **element** variable of the **getValues.js** file but the XPath scraper information code is not working at all. Maybe I'm missing something in **getValues.js** script code or is totally wrong since this is my first attempt in creating a Google chrome extension.

I hope you guys can help me.

Best regards and have a great day!

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm for your response. I have check the Redder example but just shows how to change body color.
I was able to get  the whole webpage content using this code var webContent = document.body.innerText; but I cannot write on popup showroom.html file. Any  advice?

Comment: You should avoid using absolute xpath's because they are fragile and they easily can break, instead try getting relative ones.

Comment: Thank you Lauda. Already changed the code. I managed gathering the information I wanted using the content script getValues.js and showing the total sum on a alert() message. Now I should learn how to send that sum message to the popup.js in order to show it in the popup.html.